# birt parameter box modify tab index

Tags: parameters, birt, tabindex

Is there a way we can tweak the tab index of birt parameter dialog box, like a javascript or something? I have a report that has 5 parameters. The dialog box opens up with scroll bar but is set focused to the last parameter(5th) box (a textbox). Client wants it to focus on the first parameter at the top. I can't see any way aside from modifying the BIRT default parameter box js code. thanks

Comment: What is the version of birt? With Eclipse designer 4.3.1 i don't see the same. I have reports with upto 28 parameters and the first parameter is always focused when the dialog box opens. Are all your parameters setup as textbox?

Comment: my birt is 3.7. When I run it in my local, it does go to first (top) parameter but when deployed to both windows and linux OS, it sets focus to last (bottom). No, my params are mixed with combobox, listbox and textboxes. tnx

Comment: Are you using Dynamic or Static list values?  Can you post a screen shot of the "edit Parameter" window?  If you are using Static, you should be able to the default value to the first value, and overcome the challenge.